# Do DOM-events that are not removed in "beforeDestroy" cause a memory leak?

Tags: vue.js, dom-events

If you use `addEventListener` to add events to an element, for example to the root element in the `mounted()` hook as in

```
mounted() {
    this.$el.addEventListener("wheel", this.handler);
},
```

do you have to call `removeEventListener` in the `beforeDestroy()` hook to remove it when the component is destroyed and would this cause a memory leak if you don't, or does it not matter?

Comment: In that specific case you may get away with it but it's a bit of an odd case. For an element inside the component you'd add the listener inside the template, not in `mounted`. Events registered in `mounted` are typically on external elements, like the document body, which would need removing manually.